# rostest fails when run using "catkin_make run_tests"

Tags: ros, python, rostest, rospy, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a node and some_test.test file like this:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find some_package)/launch/node.launch"/> <!-- python node using messages from my_msgs -->
  <test test-name="test_node_api" pkg="some_package" type="test_node_api.py" />
</launch>
```

The node and test script "test_node_api.py" both import messages from some other package (my_msgs). The node itself works fine (roslaunch some_package node.launch). When I run the test like this:

```
rostest art_db art_db.test
```

it also works fine (passes). However, when I use "catkin_make run_tests" the node (in node.launch) fails to start with import error of my_msgs.msg module. What might be wrong?

The CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(some_package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  my_msgs
  rospy
  roslint
)

set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--max-line-length=250")
roslint_python()
roslint_add_test()

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS my_msgs)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rostest roslaunch)
  roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)
  add_rostest(tests/some_test.test)
endif()
```

UPDATE:

Results can be seen here (some_package is actually art_db): http://pastebin.com/qu7SfLK6 - line 143 says "ImportError: No module named art_msgs.msg". However, if I do "catkin_make" several times, the "catki_make run_tests" eventually gives success. Calling "rostest art_db art_db.test" always leads to success. The package can be found here: https://github.com/ZdenekM/ar-table-itable/tree/master/art_db.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250056/rostest-fails-when-run-using-%22catkin_make-run_tests%22/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-15**:
Would you mind sharing the error output?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2016-12-19**:
Similar question found: http://answers.ros.org/question/220540/defining-a-dependency-for-a-python-add_rostest-call/ - however in my case I believe that messages are built but module can't be found for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered on github: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/841

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0